# Getting attributes in PyQuery?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, pyquery

I'm using PyQuery and want to print a list of links, but can't figure out how to get the `href` attribute from each link in the PyQuery syntax.

This is my code:

```
  e = pq(url=results_url)
  links = e('li.moredetails a')
  print len(links)
  for link in links:
    print link.attr('href')
```

This prints `10`, then gives the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'attr'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

PyQuery wraps [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/), so you use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to access attributes:

```
e = pq(url=results_url)
for link in e('li.moredetails a'):
    print link.attrib['href']
```

Alternatively, to use the PyQuery API on any found element, wrap the element in a `pq()` call, echoing the way you need to use jQuery `$()` or `jQuery()` to wrap DOM elements:

```
    print pq(link).attr('href')
```

or

```
    print pq(link).attr['href']
```

for a more pythonic way to accessess the attributes.

You could also loop over the `.items()` method instead, which returns PyQuery elements instead:

```
e = pq(url=results_url)
for link in e('li.moredetails a').items():
    print link.attr['href']
```

Comment: Is the `pq(...).attr()` method documented?  I don't see it in the API doc:  https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/api.html

Comment: @JoeCoder: see the [quickstart](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/index.html), where the `PyQuery` is imported and bound to the name `pq`.

Answer (score 3):

As in jQuery, wrap that link up:

```
e = pq(url=results_url)
links = e('li.moredetails a')
print len(links)
for link in links:
    print pq(link).attr('href')
```